# JavaFX stage show function not working on MAC OS

Tags: javafx-11

I am facing issue with JavaFx Application on Mac os. When I call show() function on primaryStage, same is not displaying anything on Gui and app crashes. App is working fine on linux and Windows. Here Jdk version is 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that issue was due to use of wrong Netty WebSocket in Project on Mac OS. Nio should be used but I used Epoll.